# Can I say "Have a good week." to somebody I know I will see every day of the week?

Tags: phrase-usage

When speaking with a co-worker of mine, who doesn't work during the weekends like me, I could tell him "Have a good weekend." before returning at home. If I tell him "Have a good weekend." on a different weekday, that would mean I will not see him again before Friday, or I think that is going to happen.

If I say "Have a good week." before leaving work, does that mean I will not see him for the rest of the week, or is that something I can say even if I will see him throughout the week?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying "Have a good week" in most cases would mean that you will not be seeing him for the rest of the week or at least you believe so. It could also mean that you know that he had a rough last week and to cheer him up on a Monday morning, or while leaving on a Monday evening, you tell him "Have a good week" and in this case, you may or may not be seeing him for the rest of the week and it wasn't the dominant factor behind you making that remark.